# Auto format feature in Dev-C++ IDE

Tags: c++, windows, ide, dev-c++, astyle

In Eclipse I would always use `Ctrl + shift + f` to autoformat code in the IDE.

Is there a similar feature in [Dev-C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html), or some plugin available that I can use for formatting my C/C++ code?

Comment: Since the accepted answer gives a commercial software as the solution, I'd like to disagree and add a free alternative that does the work - https://sourceforge.net/projects/astyle/files/ . One can use the same steps that are present in the accepted answer to use this formatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of all this mentioned below, just Press Shift + Ctrl+ A

Download this.

http://www.formatcode.com/download.php

Format Source Code within Dev-C++

The following instructions allow you to format source code files in Dev-C++ using FormatCode command line tool.

Add a Tool Menu that will invoke FormatCode

1. Click "Tools" -> "Configure Tools...".
2. Click the "Add" button to add a new tool.
3. Assuming you installed FormatCode in C:\Program Files\FormatCode, fill in the form as show below:

   Title:                       FormatCode
   Program:                 C:\Program Files\FormatCode\FormatCode.exe
   Working Directory:   C:\Program Files\FormatCode
   Parameters:             "SOURCENAME"
4. Click "OK" button to save settings.

You may now invoke FormatCode command line tool:

1. By clicking "Tools" -> "FormatCode".("AnyStyler)

Comment: I'll try that out. Cheers

Comment: it's commercial.

Comment: @LeiYang yes - I found a free alternative instead - https://sourceforge.net/projects/astyle/files/ You can set it up using the same steps in the given answer. Hope this helps others too.